# Angular directive not rendering with templateUrl in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive

In chrome - **both** variants work. However, when emulating ios - the directive using templateUrl does **not** work.

This **does not work in the ios emulator** but does work in the browser:

```
angular.directive('listitems', function(ApiEndpoint) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: '../template/listitems.ng.html',
    scope: true
  };
})
```

This **works in the ios emulator and works in the browser**:

```
angular.directive('listitems', function(ApiEndpoint) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<strong>listitems</strong>',
    scope: true
  };
})
```

Elsewhere using templateUrl works just fine in both the browser and ios emulator. For example when using ui router - I'm able to load external templates without issues:

```
$stateProvider.state('app.dashboard', {
  url: "/dashboard",
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: '../template/dashboard.ng.html',
      controller: 'DigstackDashboard'
    }
  }
});
```

My question is - in the case of the directive, why would the templateUrl value not work only in the ios emulator?

Comment: I'll update my question - ApiEndpoint is a constant

Comment: Please tell me the whole path of `listitems.ng.html`

Comment: [app]/www/templates/listitems.ng.html Please note that this path works ok when rendering in a browser - and also when using ui-router. Just not with a directive.

Comment: Which server you are using to run the app?

Comment: I'm running gulp remove-proxy && ionic emulate ios --target="iPhone-5" to start the emulator. I'm running my services using vagrant - and modified my /etc/hosts file to accept traffic from the configured domain.

Comment: Can you please provide the file names and their paths that contains the above code. Can you please provide a plunker?

Comment: the file examples above are in [app]/www/js/app.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131768/discussion-between-charan-cherry-and-bas-kuis).

Comment: Shoot! :-) it was so late.. I fell asleep! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue! I hope this will help somebody else.

```
angular.config(function($sceDelegateProvider){
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
         'self',
         'https://www.example.com/**'
    ]);
 }
```

Even though in uirouter - this does not seem to be needed. In the ios emulator - this configuration was required to get templates to load.